# Is it possible to subscribe the same topic twice?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm working on ROS kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04.

I just wonder whether I can subscribe same topic by two or more Subscribers.

For example, once i run turtlebot bringup pkg, many other topics should be published.

In this situation, can i subscribe the same Odom topic at node_A and node_B simultaneously??

Thanks in advance. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333019/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-the-same-topic-twice?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.
Multiple nodes can subscribe to the same topic.
Multiple nodes can publish to the same topic.

I believe that each subscriber gets it's own buffer so there is no worry that one subscriber will get one message and the other subscriber will miss it - and if I'm wrong about that, I'm sure someone will be along shortly to correct me.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1